# Flutter GeoLocator PermissionRequestInProgressException

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I'm using the Flutter Geolocator package, and use the following code:

```
  void determinePosition() async {
    Position currentPosition;

    try {
      currentPosition = await Geolocator
          .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);

    } on TimeoutException {
      _streamError('Location request timed out.');

    } on PermissionDeniedException {
      _streamError('Location permissions are denied.');

    } on LocationServiceDisabledException {
      _streamError('Location services are disabled.');

    } on PermissionRequestInProgressException {
      _streamError('Permission in progress.');
      // Do nothing. A strange bug in the library that causes an exception on first request IMO
    }

    _streamSuccess(currentPosition);
  }
```

It works 'well', in that the the user is asked for allowance as shown here:

[image]

However, it throws an exception when I tap 'allow once':

[image]

The second time I go through the code, the current location is fetched as expected.

Obviously I could fix this problem by calling `determinePosition` recursively on exception with some fail counter, but I find that solution extremely stupid.

Anyone else been having this problem, or what is the reason I get this exception?
Expected behaviour is obviously to return the current location on 'allow' tap.
Haven't been able to find info on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Went with the bad solution, no time to waste on silly issues:

```
  Future<void> determinePosition() async {
    Position currentPosition;

    try {
      currentPosition = await Geolocator
          .getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best
      );
      _retryCount = 0;

    } on TimeoutException {
      _streamError('Location request timed out.');

    } on PermissionDeniedException {
      _streamError('Location permissions are denied.');

    } on LocationServiceDisabledException {
      _streamError('Location services are disabled.');

    } on PermissionRequestInProgressException {
      if (_retryCount < RETRY_COUNT) {
        _retryCount++;
        await determinePosition();
      }
    }

    _streamSuccess(currentPosition);
  }
```

I made a mention here: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/450